# apache flink with Kafka: InvalidTypesException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have following code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MyCustomClassDeserializer.class.getName());

FlinkKafkaConsumer<MyCustomClass> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer(
                    "test-kafka-topic",
                    new SimpleStringSchema(),
                    properties);

final StreamExecutionEnvironment streamEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<MyCustomClass> kafkaInputStream = streamEnv.addSource(kafkaConsumer);

DataStream<String> stringStream = kafkaInputStream
                    .map(new MapFunction<MyCustomClass,String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String map(MyCustomClass message) {
                            logger.info("--- Received message : " + message.toString());
                            return message.toString();
                        }
                    });

streamEnv.execute("Published messages");
```

MyCustomClassDeserializer is implemented to convert byte array to java object.

When I run this program locally, I get error:

Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Input mismatch: Basic type expected.

And I get this for code line:

```
.map(new MapFunction<MyCustomClass,String>() {
```

Not sure why I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, You have a deserializer that returns POJO, yet You are telling Flink that it should deserialize record from `byte[]` to `String` by using `SimpleStringSchema`. 
See the problem now? :)

I don't think You should use the custom Kafka deserializers in `FlinkKafkaConsumer` in general. What You should aim for instead is to instead create a custom class that extends `DeserializationSchema` from Flink. It should be much better in terms of type safety and testability.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Actually its a legacy code, with too many such issues.